# Setting home catalogs to a different drive

Tags: linux, permissions, home-folder

First time admin here.

I'm setting up an RPi as a server for the family and myself.

I have attached an external ext4 hard drive and set up folders for each family member there. Each folder has a path like "*/home/pi/extdrive/username*".

I would now like to turn these folders into the respective user's home folder, so that the users are directed there instead of to the "*/home/username*" folder on the Pi's SD card. Can I have some tips on how to do this without destroying the file system?

Furthermore, there is a common music library on the external drive (*/home/pi/extdrive/music*). I am the owner of that folder while everyone else have read permissions to it. Can I link to the music folder from each user's folder, so that they can access it through logging into their own folder?

Comment: Google "move /home" and you will find instructions.